# Spring interceptor is not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am getting started with spring interceptors and wanted to simply log the time of invocation of each request.

**My Interceptor class:**

```
package com.ankit.notice.interceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class ExecuteTimeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time is " + startTime);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ankit.notice" />
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.ankit.notice.interceptor.ExecuteTimeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors> 

   .....
</beans>
```

**Controller Class**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/getAllItems.rest", method =     RequestMethod.GET)  
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getAllItems(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> responseEntity = null;
        Map<String, Object> responseParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        try {
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
            if ((null == user) || (user.getId() < 0)) {
                throw new MNPSessionException(
                        "INVALID USER : Session attribute user is not set correctly");
            }
         ....
     }
```

I have no request mapping for the controller class, instead I am mapping requests directly to methods. (I know that is a bad practice, but I am working on it :) )

**web.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  


http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.rest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

 <filter>
    <filter-name>sessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ankit.notice.util.SessionCheckFilter</filter-class>
</filter>  

filter-mapping>
<filter-name>sessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**Request URL** **`localhost:8080/mvc/api/getAllItems.rest`**

As per my understanding since no mapping is provided in the `mvc:interceptors` tag, the interceptor should be invoked for all requests.

In my console, no sysout outputs are available. I tried returning false to ensure that there is no issue with interceptors and sysout but no avail.

Also, I tried removing removing `mvc:annotation-driven` tag, but the interceptor is not invoked.

Any pointers what might be wrong here? There were other options like creating bean of class `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` and creating bean of class `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` with properties:`list` and `mapping`, but none of them work. Can someone point out the difference between these methods and give directions when to use which?

Comment: What request url are you testing. Provide the the controller class and web.xml and application configuration

Answer (score 1):

To "override" the interceptor I used the configuration class **annotated with** **@Configuration** (created inside  a "config" package).

There's no need to use any xml configuration.

```
package com.abc.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.abc.interceptor.BaseInterceptor;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new BaseInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would swear that you have forgotten the "mvc:interceptor" tag inside the "mvc:interceptors" tag:

Could you try the following?

```html
<mvc:interceptors>
  
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean  id="executeTimeInterceptor"  class="com.ankit.notice.interceptor.ExecuteTimeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
  
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I had tried the same before posting the question, but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry by asking again, but Did you try to include the mvc:mapping path="/**" in the bean interceptor definition? Another question: Could you try to make a more simple test with only a spring context? You have both root-context.xml and servlet-context.xml .... may be You could try with only one servlet-context.xml and move your bean interceptor there ...

Comment: Yes, I tried that,didn't work. Also, do you mean web.xml when you say servlet-context.xml ? If yes, then as per spring docs, the interceptors should be defined in application context i.e root-context.xml here. Please refer [spring docs advisory](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

Comment: Hello Again, I would ask you if Did  you find the solution with the spring interceptors. I have coded a similar Spring MVC App in GitHub and the spring interceptors are working ok for me. I share you the GitHub link if you want  compare it with your code:  [https://github.com/PabloEzequiel/Java/tree/master/myApiRest](https://github.com/PabloEzequiel/Java/tree/master/myApiRest) I have also tried some fragments from your code in my example, and these are working ok, so I can't find where are an error in the code that  you have copied in this question, because your code is working ok in the mine